# OpenCV setup in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I setup eclipse IDE to use openCV. I followed the tutorial provided on openCV website. However, there is this extremely annoying issue am facing every time I create a new project. It seems I need to redo the entire process of pasting the library files in GCC C++ linker for every project that I create. Is there anyway of making them persistent for all new projects ? Or to at least be able to export the settings so that I can import them which will save time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question, but if you just don't want to set up the project each time, you can save a **build configuration** in Eclipse.

**To use another projects build configuration:**

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build

Click Manage Configurations and create a new config (call it opencv or whatever).

Then set up your Includes, GCC linker etc as you have done before. Then hit Apply.

Now if you ever want to set up a new project with these configs, select your new project:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Manage Configurations

Click New and select 'Import from projects' and select your 'opencv' configuration. This will import the build set-up into the your new project.

Then just select it from the Configuration drop-down.

**To export the build configuration as an XML file:**

Right click project -> Export...

Select C/C++ -> C/C++ Project Settings

Select the Configuration you want to export and save it somewhere.

**To import it into a project:**

Right click project -> Import... -> C/C++ Project Settings

and browse for your config file

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it had made things simpler. But it only allows me to load the configuration from an already existing project. Is there a way to save the configuration in a way that even if I delete the previous project I can still load it?

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to export/import build configurations as xml files, This should be what you need. Afraid I don't have a project set-up to test this on, but it should import everything correctly (maybe not the GCC linker?)